# Getting starting and ending Date of last week [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, date

I want to automate calculations of revenue for the last calender week. I am always calculating  the revenue from Monday 00:00:00 to Sunday 23:59:59. Note: The exact time 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 are important here.

At the moment im using the following very basic script:

select sum(base_subtotal)
from sales_flat_order 
where created_at between '2014-09-08 00:00:00' and '2014-09-14 23:59:59'

Now i dont want to update the date everytime i run the query because if have lots of those queries. How can sql automatically get the starting and ending dates with the exact time?

I'm using MySQL.

Thx so far ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(base_subtotal)
from sales_flat_order
where created_at between 
  CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) + 7 DAY
  AND
 (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY) - INTERVAL 1 SECOND
```